Getting Invalid Argument error from Google Business Profile API while trying to create a location
I am using Google's Business API to add a location from my Node.js application, but I'm encountering the following error:
{
    "error": "Request contains an invalid argument."
}

I am using the googleapis npm package and tried by commenting out all optional fields, leaving only the required fields in the request body. But, I'm still encountering an error. Here is my code:
app.post('/add-location', async (req, res) => {
    const { location, tokens } = req.body;
    oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);

    const mybusinessbusinessinformation = google.mybusinessbusinessinformation('v1');
    try {
        const response = await mybusinessbusinessinformation.accounts.locations.create({
            parent: 'accounts/' + process.env.ACCOUNT_ID,
            validateOnly: true,
            requestId: uuidv4(),
            requestBody: {


                // "name": "EVgo Charging Station",
                // "languageCode": "en",
                // "storeCode": "EVG123",
                "title": "EVgo Charging Station",
                // "phoneNumbers": {
                //     "primaryPhone": "+1 123-456-7890"
                // },
                // "categories": {
                //     "primaryCategory": {
                //         "name": "categories/gcid:electric_vehicle_charging_station",
                //         "displayName": "Electric vehicle charging station",
                //     },
                // },
                // "storefrontAddress": {
                //     "regionCode": "US",
                //     "locality": "Durham",
                //     "postalCode": "27707",
                //     "addressLines": ["4711 Hope Valley Rd", "Woodcroft Shopping Center"]
                // },
                // "websiteUri": "https://evgo.com",
                // "regularHours": {
                //     "periods": [
                //         {
                //             "openDay": "MONDAY",
                //             "openTime": {
                //                 "hours": 0,
                //                 "minutes": 0
                //             },
                //             "closeDay": "SUNDAY",
                //             "closeTime": {
                //                 "hours": 23,
                //                 "minutes": 59
                //             }
                //         }
                //     ]
                // },
                // "specialHours": {
                //     "specialHourPeriods": [
                //         {
                //             "startDate": {
                //                 "year": 2024,
                //                 "month": 12,
                //                 "day": 25
                //             },
                //             "endDate": {
                //                 "year": 2024,
                //                 "month": 12,
                //                 "day": 25
                //             },
                //             "closed": true
                //         }
                //     ]
                // },
                // "labels": [
                //     "EV Charging",
                //     "Fast Charging"
                // ],
                // "latlng": {
                //     "latitude": 35.951033,
                //     "longitude": -78.956228
                // },
                // "openInfo": {
                //     "status": "OPEN",
                //     "canReopen": true
                // },
                // "metadata": {
                //     "mapsUri": "https://maps.google.com/?q=EVgo+Charging+Station",
                //     "newReviewUri": "https://maps.google.com/review?place_id=ChIJzxbB6Gs7bIcRZZrPTeyb-0A"
                // },
                "profile": {
                    "description": "Fast and reliable electric vehicle charging station."
                },
                // "relationshipData": {
                //     "parentChain": "EVgo"
                // },
                // "moreHours": [
                //     {
                //         "hoursTypeId": "DRIVE_THROUGH",
                //         "periods": [
                //             {
                //                 "openDay": "MONDAY",
                //                 "openTime": {
                //                     "hours": 0,
                //                     "minutes": 0
                //                 },
                //                 "closeDay": "SUNDAY",
                //                 "closeTime": {
                //                     "hours": 23,
                //                     "minutes": 59
                //                 }
                //             }
                //         ]
                //     }
                // ],
            },
            auth: oauth2Client
        });
        console.log(response)
        res.send(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        res.status(400).send({ error: error.message });
    }
});

here is detailed log
GaxiosError: Request contains an invalid argument.
    at Gaxios._request (/Users/workstation/Programming/Clients/-/gmb-microservice/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:142:23)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async OAuth2Client.requestAsync (/Users/workstation/Programming/Clients/-/gmb-microservice/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:429:18)
    at async /Users/workstation/Programming/Clients/-/gmb-microservice/server.js:52:26 {
  config: {
    url: 'https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/102094468378068712054/locations?validateOnly=true&requestId=54e30089-a836-441c-8eb0-bdd936c0a979',
    method: 'POST',
    apiVersion: '',
    userAgentDirectives: [ [Object] ],
    paramsSerializer: [Function (anonymous)],
    data: { title: 'EVgo Charging Station', profile: [Object] },
    headers: {
      'x-goog-api-client': 'gdcl/7.2.0 gl-node/20.8.0',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip',
      'User-Agent': 'google-api-nodejs-client/7.2.0 (gzip)',
      Authorization: '<<REDACTED> - See `errorRedactor` option in `gaxios` for configuration>.',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    params: {
      validateOnly: true,
      requestId: '54e30089-a836-441c-8eb0-bdd936c0a979'
    },
    validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],
    retry: true,
    body: '{"title":"EVgo Charging Station","profile":{"description":"Fast and reliable electric vehicle charging station."}}',
    responseType: 'unknown',
    errorRedactor: [Function: defaultErrorRedactor],
    retryConfig: {
      currentRetryAttempt: 0,
      retry: 3,
      httpMethodsToRetry: [Array],
      noResponseRetries: 2,
      retryDelayMultiplier: 2,
      timeOfFirstRequest: 1722445004419,
      totalTimeout: 9007199254740991,
      maxRetryDelay: 9007199254740991,
      statusCodesToRetry: [Array]
    }
  },
  response: {
    config: {
      url: 'https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/102094468378068712054/locations?validateOnly=true&requestId=54e30089-a836-441c-8eb0-bdd936c0a979',
      method: 'POST',
      apiVersion: '',
      userAgentDirectives: [Array],
      paramsSerializer: [Function (anonymous)],
      data: [Object],
      headers: [Object],
      params: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function (anonymous)],
      retry: true,
      body: '{"title":"EVgo Charging Station","profile":{"description":"Fast and reliable electric vehicle charging station."}}',
      responseType: 'unknown',
      errorRedactor: [Function: defaultErrorRedactor]
    },
    data: { error: [Object] },
    headers: {
      'alt-svc': 'h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000',
      'cache-control': 'private',
      'content-encoding': 'gzip',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      date: 'Wed, 31 Jul 2024 16:56:44 GMT',
      server: 'ESF',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      vary: 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
      'x-xss-protection': '0'
    },
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    request: {
      responseURL: 'https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/102094468378068712054/locations?validateOnly=true&requestId=54e30089-a836-441c-8eb0-bdd936c0a979'
    }
  },
  error: undefined,
  status: 400,
  code: 400,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Request contains an invalid argument.',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'badRequest'
    }
  ],
  [Symbol(gaxios-gaxios-error)]: '6.7.0'
}

Also, Is there detailed documentation available for the Google Business API in the googleapis npm package?
I am following the following URL for creating the request body
https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations#Location

There were some other required items that I identified after adding some additional logs.
It seems, A location cannot be added under an Organization Account. Therefore, I created a Location Group Account under the Organization and used that Location Group Account ID. Finally it worked.
Here is the detailed explanation.
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/3530
